# Create a new clipboard

Tags: vb.net, window

In vb.net is there anyway to create or new a new clipboard instead of using the native clipboard from the OS itself?

Answer (score 0):

start with a "Clipboard hook". Here's article that implements a Clipboard hook.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19858/Global-Windows-Hooks